# Tango With Django Tutorial: No module named 'conf.urls'

Tags: python, django

I am going through the [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/) tutorial, and I am attempting to get the 'Hello World!' server running (Chapter 3). However, using the code presented on that site, I obtain the following error:
[image: ImportError]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your urls.py you should have `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url` not just `conf.urls` in the import